# Triple integral for a partial cylinder

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I encounter this question in my homework and i am stuck with it. The question is as follows:

(a) Find the mass of a solid $U$ with density $\delta(x,y,z)=2020$, where $U$ is bounded by 3 given surface: $x^2+y^2=2020, z=x^2+y^2$ and the xy-plane.

(b) Find the centre of mass of the same solid U described in (a)

I have some rough idea on dealing with part (a).$x^2+y^2=2020$ represents a circular cylinder with radius $\sqrt{2020}$ while $z=x^2+y^2$ represents a elliptic paraboloid inside the circular cylinder and they both should have height of $2020$. Therefore, the volume of this solid should be $\frac{1}{4}$ of the volume of cylinder minus $\frac{1}{4}$ of the volume of the elliptic paraboliod since they are bounded by the xy-plane. Then the mass would be $2020$ times the volume.

However, i have trouble finding the triple integral for the elliptic paraboloid. Also, can i use a single triple integral to find the mass so i could do part (b), or is it not necessary? Really appreciate your guys help.

Comment: You can use a single integral by summing annuli or discs along the z direction. A separate integral is needed for (b) to sum the moment of mass of each annulus or disc about the x or y axis. You do not need a factor of $\frac14$ if you use limits of z=0 to z=2020.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But how exactly can i sum up annuli along the z direction? I am not familiar with this since i am new to triple integral

Comment: It is a single integral not a triple integral. The element of volume $dV$ is an annulus of inner radius $r_1=\sqrt{z}$ and outer radius $r_2=\sqrt{2020}$ and thickness $dz$.